# C# passing message through serialport

Tags: c#, matlab, unity-game-engine, serial-port

I am trying to run a treadmill using the serial port, I was able to do it using matlab however I am having a few probelms when I ported the same code to C#. I am sure that the port is open there is probably something wrong with the message format. Would be great if someone can tell me what mistake I am making.The matlab code (which works) and the C# code (which doesn't work) are given below.

MATLAB CODE :

```
ctr = char(12); %control character
rel = char(169); %release
set_speed = char(163);
set_dir = char (184);

 %initializing the ports
R = serial('COM4'); 
set(R, 'BaudRate', 4800, 'Parity', 'none', 'DataBits', 8, 'StopBits', 1, 'Terminator', 'CR');
set(R, 'InputBufferSize', 128, 'OutputBufferSize', 128);
fopen(R);


if R.status == 'open'
   fprintf(R, [rel ctr]);    
   disp('port for R belt open and released');
else
   disp('error with R port-- COM3');
end;


%initial direction to FORWARD
fprintf(R, [set_dir '0' char(12)]);

%set speed to 
fprintf(R, [set_speed '0005' ctr]);
```

My C# version of the matlab code above

```
char ctr = (char)12;
char rel = (char)169; //release 
char set_speed = (char)163;
char set_dir = (char)184;

void Start () {

    try{

        SerialPort R = new SerialPort();
        R.BaudRate = 4800;
        R.Parity = Parity.None;
        R.DataBits = 8;
        R.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        R.ReadBufferSize = 128;
        R.WriteBufferSize = 128;


        R.Open();



       if(R.IsOpen){
            //Release
            R.Write(rel+""+ctr);
            print ("Serial port is open");
       }
       else print ("Serial  port is close");

        R.Write(set_dir+""+"0"+""+ctr);

       R.Write(set_speed+""+"0005"+""+ctr);
    }
    catch(UnityException e){
        print ("Exception");
        print (e);      

    }



}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: Also, what is "print"? If you are trying to write to the console use Console.WriteLine().

Comment: At least add the error message or any description of what is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with C#, but I'll try to guess that you should also send *terminator* character in your C# code.

Check the [fprintf (serial)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html) documentation in MatLab:

> *fprintf(obj,'cmd')* writes the string cmd to the device connected to the serial port object, obj. The default format is %s\n. The write operation is synchronous and blocks the command-line until execution completes.
>   *fprintf(obj,'format','cmd')* writes the string using the format specified by format.

In your calls you are using 1st syntax so your call

```
fprintf(R, [rel ctr]);
```

is actually

```
fprintf(R, '%s\n', [rel ctr]);
```

Usually, serial devices read input data until the terminator character is found. This means that transmission of the command string or data is completed and the device now can execute the command. This is much like hitting ENTER in MatLab command window: command is executed only after you do this.
Which terminator character to use should be specified in your device programming manual.
Seems that `CR` is OK since your MatLab code works.

In your MatLAb code you set the terminator to be `CR` character (ASCII code 13). I do not see this in your C# code so your device waits for `CR` which is not sent so there should be no reaction from your device.
I do not think that C# will send the terminator character for you, you should take care of it by yourself.

My guess is that

```
R.Write(rel+""+ctr + "\r");
```

should solve the problem (thanks dodald for reminding me that I missed the proper conclusion).

See also [Terminator property of SERIAL object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/terminator.html) and [Rules for Writing the Terminator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/writing-and-reading-data.html#br8pqg6-1).

Comment: So to answer, salman should be able to just add '\r' to the end of the string in the C# code. (\r being the CR char)

e.g. R.Write(rel+""+ctr + "\r");

Comment: Seems like it. At least this is the difference I spotted between MatLab and C# versions.

Comment: Alternatively, he could simply use the WriteLine method.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager, Does it work the same way as in MatLab documentation on `fprintf (serial)` function: `When performing a write operation using the fprintf function, all occurrences of \n are replaced with the Terminator property value` or it simply writes `CR` or `CRLF` characters depending on win/lin platform?

Comment: @anandr, Of that I'm not 100% sure. I've used the SerialPort class before, and almost always with WriteLine without any problems.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager, It also depends on designers of the particular device and their will and ability to follow standards (I've seen a device which recognized only TAB character as terminator, which is just stupid IMHO). So lets wait for some feedback from OP.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager,@anandr The SerialPort class writes a specified line terminator (the "NewLine" property, which can be changed). By default it uses the LF. So OP could use WriteLine and set the NewLine property to CR.

e.g. R.NewLine = "\r";

Comment: \r and WriteLine did not work as terminals, I thought ctr ((char)12) was the terminal. There are no error messages and I should also mention that I am using Unity3D.

Comment: @salman, then I suggest to use serial port monitor program to analyze MatLab<->device and C#<->device communication and find the differences (long time ago I successfully used such program). Just look for pure software solution to "intercept" RS-232 communication.

Comment: So after using a seriol port monitoring software, I have discovered that all values passed through the port which are greater than 127 show up as 63 (CF). So there must be some buffer overflow but I can't figure out where.

Comment: That's weird. Never seen that buffer overflow can change the transmitted data. This looks more like inability to show correctly upper (codes 128 to 255) characters by your program or by the font you selected in your program (the upper part of the extended ASCII table usually contains characters for non-latin alphabets depending on the codepage used). But you should compare ray bytes not their representation.